# REST API V2: Converting String type parameter to List type

Tags: rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm trying to execute a *JasperReports* report through REST V2 services by passing the param value as part of the url. Then, in report, I have a SQL which take a list type param. But how to convert the String type param to List type to run the query?

Here, the String param has the comma separated values like below:

> https://[host_name]:[port]/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/samples/[report_name].pdf?param_str=value1,value2,value3

we need to convert param_str to a List type from String type.

I'm getting the cast exception like :

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe I am doing this, it seems you can earn quite a lot on Jasper obscure and badly documented area by doing consulting. But I work with open source tech so should have the correct mindset. :-)

Here you are **param_str=value1&param_str=value2&param_str=value3**

If you find out how to do the same with Map, pls tell.